# How do I efficiently count elements less than a certain value in a sorted array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Say for example I have a sorted array:

```
[21, 32, 58, 70, 100, 4342]
```

And a key value `80`

How do I efficiently count all values from 80 below without iterating through the whole array with an if condition? I was thinking Binary Search but then again i'm not searching for any key, I just need the fastest way return the count of values less than or equal to key value.

Comment: With binary search you can find the index to the value 80, and then the index is the number of the elements less than 80 (assuming ascending order).

Comment: or, stream, filter, ...

Comment: "I was thinking Binary Search but then again i'm not searching for any key" - well you are, in that you're trying to find *where that key lives in the array* (or where it would be if it did exist).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Arrays.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int%5B%5D,%20int)). According to the documentation it returns the *index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; otherwise, `(-(insertion point) - 1)`*. Using your example:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] arr = {21, 32, 58, 70, 100, 4342};

        int res70 = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, 70);// returns 3
        int res80 = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, 80);// returns -5
    }
}
```

With that in mind, you can use that information to get an efficient count: if the result is positive, the count is `result`, if the result is negative, the count is `(-result)-1` or `-(result+1)` (depending on your preference):

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] arr = {21, 32, 58, 70, 100, 4342};

        System.out.println("Count is:" + count(arr, 70));// returns 3
        System.out.println("Count is:" + count(arr, 80));// returns 4
    }

    private static int count(int[] sortedArray, int n) {
        int result = Arrays.binarySearch(sortedArray, n);
        if (result > -1) {
            return result;
        }
        return (-result) - 1;
    }
}
```

For the case where duplicates are possible, and multiple 80s exist in the array, there are two possible solutions:

1. Do a linear search from the result of the binary search. This would make the worst-case `O(n)` though, while still being `O(lg n)` on average.
2. Manually implement (or find a library that has) a binary search to find the last element equal to a value (while preserving the consideration for the element not found as the Java library does). An example of finding the last element exists in this answer: [Last index of multiple keys using binary-search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415408/last-index-of-multiple-keys-using-binary-search/14415588#14415588) That would keep worst-case at `O(lg n)`.

Comment: I know that we were probably writing the answer at the same time, but please make sure all special cases are handled properly. 1+ for giving example code.

Comment: thanks for the point @gthanop ! I added some considerations at the end of the answer to consider the case of duplicates.

Comment: No problem. Also, welcome to SO. To be honest, I couldn't think of the solution you provided in the edit. Nice job done. This should be the answer now (because it is more complete).

Comment: Why count(70) returns 4? is 70 counted too?

Comment: You are absolutely right @AlessandroParisi, I reviewed and edited the response accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since *Java 9* you can use [`takeWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.IntPredicate-) and [`dropWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#dropWhile-java.util.function.IntPredicate-) methods if the source array is *ordered*:

```java
int key = 80, arr[] = {21, 32, 58, 70, 100, 4342};

System.out.println("Count: " + Arrays.stream(arr)
        .takeWhile(i -> i < key)
        .peek(i -> System.out.print(i + " "))
        .count()); // 21 32 58 70 Count: 4

System.out.println("Count: " + Arrays.stream(arr)
        .dropWhile(i -> i < key)
        .peek(i -> System.out.print(i + " "))
        .count()); // 100 4342 Count: 2
```